# Python speech recognition

Tags: python, windows

When i run this code and speak script return empty list:

```
import pyaudio
import pyttsx3
import os
import pyautogui
import speech_recognition as sr
def command():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone()
    recog = sr.Recognizer()
    with mic as u_audio:
        print('Speak please')
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(u_audio)
        voice = r.listen(u_audio)
    try:
        listening = recog.recognize_google(voice, language = 'en-EN', show_all = True)
        print(listening)
    except Exception as e:
        print('I not understand' + str(e))
        command()

command()
```

output:
speak please
[ ]
i do not understand, why list are empty. Maybe i should choose microphone index.

Answer (score 0):

The Microphone is the Problem

The problem should be possibly be on the Microphone, because I ran the same code, and it does give the Output, it gives all possible outcomes of the speech.

Anyways, it isn't efficient. Unwanted libraries slows it down, here is the updated code:

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr

def command():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone()
    recog = sr.Recognizer()

    with mic as u_audio:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(u_audio)
        print('Speak please')
        voice = r.listen(u_audio)
    try:
        listening = recog.recognize_google(voice, language = 'en-EN', show_all = True)
        print(listening)

    except Exception as e:
        print('I not understand' + str(e))
        command()

command()
```

Comment down the result!